# How to cache my website from the server side

Tags: html, caching

Is there a way i can put my website in cache by default on all the browsers from the server side?

I have a large website that i don't need to reload most of it's components once it is accessed. I rad many articles about javascript caching files but i prefer to find a more progressive way like enabling some features on my server. I hope you can help.

Comment: This is a very general question. There are many such ways - you can use proxy servers e.g. apache squid, webservers may provide caching proxy modules, tools like varnish can help as well. What webserver are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/leverage-browser-caching.html

It's basically using .htaccess file that should be on your root directory and it "tells" the server what should and how long a component to be cached.